# Exporting Data Load Editor Sections Easily

Tags: export, editor, qliksense

I need to export **all sections** (the source code inside) with one action. Now I'am copying section by section. I checked the **QMC** console but didn't find a way.

Is there a way to dump all sections code easily?

**PS:** I'm using Qlik Sense Server Ed. v3.2

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: are you speaking about the script?

Comment: Yes, scripts in the load editor sections

Comment: go to the load editor --> File --> Export to script file

Comment: I'm using Qlik Sense Server Ed. v3.2. There's no such menu. I attached screenshot.

Comment: ah sorry i was speaking about QV. In Sense there is no direct way but you can use the build-in Engine API explorer for this. your-sense-server/dev-hub --> Engine API Explorer ---> Connect to engine --> Select your app from the drop down and wait for the app to be open --> Doc - Select method --> GetScript --> Execute --> copy the script from the Execution log

Comment: its working, thanks. I can approve as an answer if you put as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Posting my comment as an answer because the comments are cleaned sometimes**

**QlikView**

1. open `Edit Script`
2. `File` menu
3. `Export to script file` option
4. Save to desired location

**Qlik Sense**

There is no direct way in Qlik Sense but the build-in `Engine API Explorer` can be used to achieve this.

1. (in the browser) navigate to `your-sense-server/dev-hub`
2. press `Engine API Explorer` from the menu on the left side
3. press `Connect to engine` button
4. Select your app from the drop down and wait for the app to be open
5. choose `GetScript` from `Doc` -> `Select method`
6. press `Execute` button below the code section
7. copy the script from the `Execution log` section in the bottom section